# aptana crashes on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, aptana

Does anyone can tell me why aptana 3.0.4 crashes on Mac OSX Lion?

Is this only my issue? I can't work with it at all. It freezes when I try to modify or open a file.

Answer (score 0):

3.0.5 seems to be working for me, but the "Problems" view never reports any warnings or errors.  I suspect it has something to do with Java on Lion since it has to be installed separate.  http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421